# How to strip multiple characters in dataframe at once

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

My data has some foreign characters and some other unicode characters and I'm trying to get rid of them to clean the data. For example, the current string values look like the Before column and the results should be look like the After column.

```
    Before                 After
Students Num #          Student Num
无差异()\nLocation       Location
/\nCity                  City
异\nPercent              Percent
```

I've tried the following code and of course it only eliminates "\n".

```
df['After'] = df['Before'].str.replace(r'[^\x00-\x7F]+', '').str.strip('\n')
```

I tried to add other strings like '()\n' in the str.strip argument but it didn't work. How do I modify my code to get rid of all the weird unicode strings?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might find that just stripping off non alphanumeric characters achieves what you want:

```py
df['After'] = df['Before'].str.replace(r'[^A-Za-z0-9\s\\]+', '').str.strip()
```

Comment: @ Tim Biegelesien Thank you and it works but then I have another issue. I didn't specify in the example above but some strings has a valid '\' in between characters. For example, "Student\Gender" has "\" in between but I'd like to keep it in this case. Your code works well but also eliminates the "\". How do I add this part to your code so that I can keep the middle \ while getting rid of other unicode strings?

Comment: @sgrimes Well the quickest fix for that would be to just add backslash to the character class, to spare it from being removed.  But this might run the risk of leaving behind a backslash which should be removed.  Try it and see if it works for you.

Comment: Biegelesien Thanks, it looks better now but also eliminates spaces between words. For example, student num to studentnum.

Comment: Use: `strip()`.

Comment: Thanks I got an error message and added .str. in front of .strip() and it worked. thanks.